# Take only numbers from string and put in an array

Tags: c#, string

ok i found this for removing all 'junk' that is not a number from a string

```
TextIN = " 0 . 1 ,2 ; 3 4 -5 6 ,7 ,8; 9 "

string justNumbers = new String(textIN.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());
```

= "0123456789"

this removes all "junk" from my string leaving me just the numbers, but still how i can modify this ,
so i can have at least one delimiter for example a  ' , ' b etween my numbers like "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9" because i need to delimit this number so i can put them in an array of ints and work with them and there are not always just one digit numbers i may have 105 , 85692 etc.. 
any help please ?!

Comment: there are negative numbers to and isDigit is wrong that only takes on number at a time , thx for corectioning me @jCoder

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also convert to numeric values like this:

```
int[] numbers = Regex.Matches(textIN, "(-?[0-9]+)").OfType<Match>().Select(m => int.Parse(m.Value)).ToArray();
```

@L.B: agreed, but nthere might be negative values, too.

Comment: There might be real numbers, complex numbers, in the form `10E3` etc. :)

Comment: Sure! So it depends on the OP's intention which kind of numbers to support (and now I see that there are no negative numbers request, so I'm partly wrong).

Comment: ok thx for completing the all idea for me :D there are negative numbers to and all kind of numbers , you completed the unknown mysteries for me

Answer (score 1):

```
string test = string.Join(",", textIN.Where(Char.IsDigit));
```

Comment: will it work for more than one digit numbers? i am not sure thats why i am asking.

Answer (score 1):

For n digit numbers you can use regex.

```
string s = String.Join(",",
                  Regex.Matches(textIN,@"\d+").Cast<Match>().Select(m=>m.Value));
```

Comment: ok this works for n numbers, you corrected my isDigit mistake :) thx

Answer (score 0):

```
string justNumbers = new String(textIN.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray()); = "0123456789"
string[] words = justNumbers.Split(',');
```

will seperate the string into an array of numbers, delimited by commas.

Comment: i think this is not even correct , but anyhow i don't need to split 0,1,2,3,..  i need maybe 0,300,450,34,1090,3,..

Comment: That code assumes you've fed in a string like this "0,1,300,53,45", it creates an array by splitting the string at each comma.